# PHP APC Cache for PHP 5.4.14

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, iis-7.5, apc

Hello I'm looking for APC extension in my PHP version and I can not find a source to download.

My php version it 5.4.16

My System it windows server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find apc binary for windows here:http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

And the link to the binary is the following http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip

According to http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_APC_in_Windows it works well with Windows Server 2003